# How do I undelete stickies (the OS X widget version)?

Tags: macos, widgets

In Mac OS X Snow Leopard, is it possible to undelete accidentally deleted stickies? (The widget version, not the application version)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup - yes. The data for all your Stickies is stored in a file called `widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences/`. If you wish to view the contents you'll want to make sure you have Property List Viewer installed (part of Apple's Developer Tools), use `plutil` to convert it from a binary plist to a standard xml plist or just use `PlistBuddy`.